# JavaScript String Multiple Replace

Tags: string, javascript

I have a small web app where I need to perform text replacement in a string. However, the normal string.replace won't work. I am modifying portions of the text and then I need to put them back in the original string. For example, if I have:

```
var text = 'TEXT 000.99 001.00 TEXT'
```

and I need to add 0.01 to each of these numbers, I have an array of results:

```
var new_vals = [001.00, 001.01]
```

Then, when I try to replace 000.99 with 001.00, it will work and give me the following string:

```
text = 'TEXT 001.00 001.00 TEXT'
```

now I face the problem. The next replacement should be 001.00 <- 001.01, but doing so would result in:

```
text = 'TEXT 001.01 001.00 TEXT'
```

My question is, do you know of any JS library that provides a replace function that can perform multiple search/replace at the same time and on a *copy* of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [str.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with  a function:

```
var text = 'TEXT 000.99 001.00 TEXT';
var new_vals = ["001.00", "001.01"];
var index = 0;
//Returns a new result string
var result = text.replace(/\b([\d.]+)\b/g, function(substr, num, offset, str){
  //See if the number is actually a number
  var num = parseFloat(num);
  //If not, return original
  if(isNaN(num))
    return substr;
  //Return the number from new_vals and increment the index
  else
    return new_vals[index++];
});
//result == "TEXT 001.00 001.01 TEXT"
```

Or, you could do the addition in the function:

```
var text = 'TEXT 000.99 001.00 TEXT';
//Returns a new result string
var result = text.replace(/\b([\d.]+)\b/g, function(substr, num, offset, str){
  //See if the number is actually a number
  var num = parseFloat(num);
  //If not, return original
  if(isNaN(num))
    return substr;
  //Return num+0.01 with 2 decimal places
  else
    return (num+0.01).toFixed(2);
});
//result == "TEXT 1.00 1.01 TEXT"
```

Comment: Thanks. I just reached the same conclusion while reading the ECMA script drafts. It says about string.replace: "once a replacement is performed, the new replacement text is not subject to further replacements." Kind of like what I wanted, a replace that works on a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the global replace regexp instead of a simple string. The simple string will replace only the first matching instance.

```
'TEXT 001.00 001.00 TEXT'.replace(/001.00/g, '001.01');
```

Comment: I did. That's when I discovered the problem. The first replacement of 000.99 with 001.00 goes well. The problem is that when I try to replace 001.00 with 001.01, it replaces the first 001.00 (the one we got after replacing 000.99) as well. I need a function that performs multiple replacements on a string while working on a copy.

Comment: Are you sure that you included the trailing 'g' in the regexp. That should force subsequent replacements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `split(' ')` the values into an array. Then modifying the specific elements using a loop. Followed by `join(' ')` to join the text back into a string.

Comment: The problem is that while in the question all the text has just one space b/w words, this might not be the case with the real text. And keeping the number of spaces intact is important for this app.